# how to get siblings SameName element with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code :

```
<div id="notfication">
    <div class="notfi-more right"></div>
    <div id="right" class="notfication-part"></div>
    <div class="notfi-more left"></div>
    <div id="left" class="notfication-part"></div>
</div>
```

I want when click on 2 div (these divs have **notfication-part** class) done this algorithm :

**first :** Get `id` clicked element

**second :** find div that had class with name = id clicked name

**third :** when find it div change display and do this : `display:block;`

I cannot do it and I am so confused...

this is my `jQuery` code:

```
var elementID = null;
$('#notfication .notfication-part').on('click',function(){

    elementID = $(this).attr('id');
    //??? I dont know how get one element that had class with name = elementID
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$('#notfication .notfication-part').on('click',function(){
    var elementID = this.id;
    $(this).parent().find("." + elementID).show();
});
```

It gets the ID, as you said (not using jQuery though - there's no need for that), and then it parses the parent's child elements, looking for anything with that ID as a class name and sets it to `show()` (display: block).

Answer (score 1):

try to put this code instead your comment:

```
$('.'+elementID).css('display','block')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#option').click(function() {
// get the class name of the option element
var className = $(this).attr("class");
// find the div with that same class name and show it
$('div').hasClass(className).show();
});
```

or

```
$('a').click(function() {
   // get class name this way
   var oldClass= $(this).className;
   //find the divs with this class name
   $('div.'+oldClass).show();
});
```